# Laravel 5 как запустить скрипт из коммандной строки

Tags: php, laravel

Если писать просто php скрипт то можно сделать в коммандной строке

```
php имя_скрипта.php
```

, а как сделать чтобы можно было запускать также скрипты на движке Laravel кроме как через wget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо создать artisan комманду
вот [здесь на русском рассказано](http://laravel.su/docs/5.0/bus) 
вот [здесь на официальном сайте](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan)

и запускать `php artisan Mycommand`